# What is the Haskell standard library?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Can the GHC-specific libraries be called the standard library? Or do only those in the Haskell 2010 report count?

Many of the GHC libraries can be implemented by the functions in the Haskell report, possibly combined with C bindings. But the others are reliant on GHC-specific extensions, since the current Haskell language as defined in the language report doesn't support it.

For example, can `Data.Array.IO` be implemented in pure standard Haskell?

Is it really okay to think that GHC *is* Haskell?

Comment: Specifically about `Data.Array.IO`, the answer is explicitly "no". [The *array* docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0) say that "*In addition to* providing the Data.Array module as specified in the Haskell 2010 Language Report, this package *also* defines the classes IArray of immutable arrays and MArray of arrays mutable within appropriate monads, as well as some instances of these classes" (emphasis mine); meanwhile, [`Data.Array.IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IO.html) is marked as "non-portable (uses Data.Array.MArray)".

Comment: As far as I know, GHC is the only current general purpose Haskell implementation. That said, you might want to check what libraries are available with `GHCJS` and `Haste`, and perhaps to branch out a bit to Haskell relatives like Purescript and Frege.

Comment: Unfortunately the Haskell community doesn't have a real consensus about what's the "standard" library. The report libraries are too limited for many uses, the GHC libraries are mainly defined by what GHC itself *needs*, the Haskell Platform was an attempt to define one but many don't like to depend on it, and Stackage and especially Hackage are too huge.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Probably you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately the Haskell community doesn't have a real consensus about what's the "standard" library.

- The [report libraries](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#x20-192000II) are too limited for many uses.
- The [GHC libraries](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/index.html) are mainly defined by what GHC itself *needs*.
- The [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) was an attempt to define one but many don't like to depend on it.
- [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) and especially [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/) are too huge.