# Why Haskell doesn't have split function?

Tags: haskell, package

In many languages there's a function that breaks strings into parts using specified delimiter. It's often called `split`. You can find it in Python, C#, Java, JavaScript. But Haskell while being quite mature still lacks such function in the standard library. I know there's a library called `split` providing exactly this function. But it's not the same as having this function in the standard library.

So while this function is so handy and usefull that many other languages added it to their standard library its actually intersting why Haskell doesn't have it. **What are the arguments behind not having it?**

UPD: The question is about `base` package i.e. Prelude. In other words why does it have `words` and `lines` but doesn't have `split`?

Comment: `Data.Text` has `splitOn`. Is that built into typical distributions now?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge C# actually has no standard library. The .NET framework is more or less the *de-facto* standard, but strictly speaking C# has no standard library.

Comment: Do you mean within `Prelude` - no external libraries? If so you should indicate this in the question as it's ambiguous.

Comment: "about base package i.e. Prelude" `base` package contains much more than just `Prelude`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/

Comment: The most general Haskell split function is `splitCap` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:splitCap

Answer (score 6):

Several Haskell modules implement a split function, in fact it even has several variants that are more generic than the variants in Python, C#, Java, etc.

The [**`split`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3), has several [*Convenience functions*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#g:2) to split a slit of `a`s:

```
splitOn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOneOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> splitOneOf ",&" "foo,bar&qux"
["foo","bar","qux"]
```

If you want to perform high performance text processing, you usually use [**`Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text) over `String`s, since these are stored in a more compact way. The [**`text`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1) has a function [**`splitOn :: Text -> Text -> [Text]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:splitOn) to split text in a list of `Text`s. Furthermore you can use [**`split :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> [Text]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:split) to split based on a condition of the character. For example:

```
Prelude Data.Text> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude Data.Text> splitOn ", " "foo,bar, qux, bla, , true"
["foo,bar","qux","bla","","true"]
Prelude Data.Text> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Text Data.Char> split isDigit "foo1bar22true"
["foo","bar","","true"]
```

**A note on the the *standard library***

The absolute minimum a Haskell standard library should support is defined in [*Part II: The Haskell 2010 Libraries* of the *Haskell'10 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#x20-192000II). The number of operations on [`Data.List`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-22800020) is quite limited.

Then there is the [`Data.List`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.12.0.0/Data-List.html) library of GHC, but this is, according to [@ØrjanJohansen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32560351/67579) mainly a superset of the functions in the Haskell report, with functions GHC needs *itself*.

The [haskell platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/contents.html) aims to distribute a set of standard packages. `split` is part of the libraries of the *full platform* as is `Data.Text`.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which was about the reason behind not having splitting functions in the standard library, i.e. `base`.

Comment: @fsestini: the point is that text processing is usually *not* done with `String`s, so it should be part of `text`.

Comment: Surely the question is about why it's not in base. Sorry for not mentioning this initially.

Comment: @Nolan: well in short, because it is not in the Haskell report, and often not very useful to do, since the `Text` module actually is advisable for string processing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there are functions that are in base but not in Haskell report.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you advice using Text instead of String for complete beginners?

Comment: @Nolan: `Text` provides a similar interface. The only drawback is that you can not make use of more generic list functions. see: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3rrlih/text_or_string/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's very important and it's not the only drawback. I can also name having to learn the concept of package, having to learn new modules, having to link external package manually (which is not always possible: imagine online contest or maybe code golf with only base allowed)

Comment: @Nolan, questions about code golf and contests are usually off-topic here. They're also of very little interest to most of the Core Libraries Committee (which guides the development of `base`) and not of great importance to most participants on the `libraries@haskell.org` mailing list, where most of these decisions are primarily discussed. If you want, you can join that list and write a proposal. I don't give it great odds.

Comment: @dfeuer thankyou for guidance. Shouldn't the committee consider all use cases?

Comment: @Nolan, Haskell started out as a research language. For a number of years it's also been used in industry. Most people who participate in development of GHC and of Haskell libraries are using it for one of those purposes. Code golf and contests don't really have much to offer the development of the language or ecosystem for things other than code golf and contests, so it's going to be a hard sell. That's not only true of Haskell; I don't think very many languages not designed specifically for golfing care about that.

Comment: @Nolan, I missed one of the big applications: education. But the teachers don't care about that either.

Answer (score 6):

In a nutshell, that's how the ecosystem rolls.

If we take "standard library" literally and look at exactly which modules are specified by [the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskell.html#haskellpa1.html), we'll find Haskell's standard library is very minimal -- not even all of *base* is included. We might reasonably widen our scope a bit, and regard [the libraries bundled with GHC](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/) as *de facto* standard. This second group includes some absolutely fundamental stuff, such as the rest of *base*, *bytestring*, *text*, *containers*, *transformers* and *mtl*.

In any case, the broader point is that the notion of a blessed set of core libraries does not play as much as a role in Haskell practice as it does in some other languages. It is entirely possible for a library to play an important role in the ecosystem without being regarded as somehow standard. The *split* library [mentioned by Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57109432/2751851), with its [555 reverse dependencies in Hackage](https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/split), arguably fits the bill.

Comment: Interesting but doesn't answer question.

Comment: @Nolan that's because the question is unanswerable. :) "Why is it that way?" -- *"because"*. Do you really want the minutes from the committee meeting where this was decided? :)

Comment: @WillNess I disagree. I want to hear the arguments, the reasons why it's not in base.

Comment: @Nolan Then you're asking the question on the wrong website.

Comment: I believe @chepner is probably referring to the fact that "there is no actual problem to be solved" and perhaps a hint of "your question is just a rant in disguise", which are both listed in the Help Center as types of questions you should avoid asking on this site.  The obvious correct answer to your question is "There are no good arguments.", and if that's unsatisfying, consider it evidence that your question isn't a good fit for SO.  Maybe Reddit would be a better forum?

Comment: @Nolan https://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html :)