# Haskell Equivalent Of Python Split Function

Tags: haskell

I know a similar question was asked here: [Why Haskell doesn't have split function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109229/why-haskell-doesnt-have-split-function)

But, I need to make a version of the split function that I program simply, using **only** the Prelude and Data.Char in Haskell. Anything else is not accepted.

```
split ::Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split separator (x:xs)= if (x==separator) then (split separator xs)
                              else [x]:(split separator xs)
```

I've attempted the problem already. However, I am a beginner in Haskell, and I still don't know what to do.

Comment: `x == separator` fails because `x` and `separator` have different types. Either the type signature you want is `Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]` (e.g., `Char -> String -> [String]`), or you need to do something more complicated than simply comparing one element of your string at a time to the separator.

Comment: That is, do you want calls like `split '-' "foo-bar-baz"`, or calls like `split "--" "foo--bar--baz"` (the result in both cases being `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`).

Comment: You can assume the separator is only character so it is limited to cases like split '-' "foo-bar-baz"

Comment: Then your declared type is wrong: it should be `Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]`.

Comment: And `x /= []` is not allowed because `x` is a `Char`, not a `String`; you are confusing the head of the list with the list itself.

Comment: how do i get it so that two consective non-separator characters are part of the same string in the output

Comment: at the moment "HELLO" would go to ["H","E","L","L","O"]

Comment: I think that is the case, but I'm not sure

Comment: but I want "HELLO WORLD" to go to  ["HELLO", "WORLD"]

Comment: The Haskell equivalent of the Python `re.split` function is `splitCap` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:splitCap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `x` is the separator, you'll prepend an empty list to the result, not just return the empty result. For example, `split '-' ""` should return `[[]]`, not `[]`, and `split '-' "-foo"` should return `["", "foo"]`, not `["foo"]`.

When `x` is *not* the separator, you don't want to just add a new singleton list to the recursive result; you want to add `x` to the first *sublist* of the result. For example, if `split '-' "foo-bar"` gets `["oo", "bar"]` as the recursive result, do you want your final result to be `["foo", "bar"]` or `["f", "oo", "bar"]`?