# Why are list insert, modify, remove function are not in prelude?

Tags: haskell

Please consider the following functions (list manipulation according to index):

```hs
modify items index value = take index items ++ value : drop (index + 1) items
insert index element items = take index items ++ element : drop index items
remove index items = take index items ++ drop (1 + index) items
```

What was the reason that Haskell people decided not to include such common use cases in the Prelude?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A list in Haskell is a *linked* list. Often working with indexes will not only produce algorithms with horrible performance, but often also are not very Haskell-ish.

Comment: IMO `!!` (as well as `head` and `tail`) should not be in the Prelude either. Basically, indices are just the wrong approach to lists. Arguably they shouldn't be called lists at all but _stacks_, which would make it clearer how they're supposed to be used.

Comment: ...That said, I definitely have a number of times defined one of those ad-hoc in my modules...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why do you say `not very Haskell-ish`? I think they are very Haskell-ish: they receive a `list` and return a new `list` - I see this pattern through Haskell and functional programming in general. To receive something, to manipulate it, and to return a newly created and manipulated copy.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker: because often one does not work with indexes. You create a new list through recursion. Getting an element by index, or setting it by index often is a sign that the algorithm can be done differently. It is also not very safe, since it is not guaranteed that the index indeed exists. That is why @leftaroundabout says that `(!!)` probably is not a good idea either.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How would I implement a function that removes a sublist from a list without using indexes? Recursion you say? I have no idea how to write such a function. Can you please write an answer with your comment explaining why `!!` and such are a bad idea and an example of how to implement `remove list sublist = ...`. Thank you :-)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And yes, I get it now why you and @leftaroundabout are saying that `!!` and `head` and `tail` should not be in the prelude.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem @leftaroundabout But, these kinds of little helper functions would be in constant use in my various projects - even if I implement them with recursion and without indexes - I will have to always copy/paste them around all the time. The `no-indexex` implementation that you are suggesting should be part of the prelude.

Comment: Voting to reopen. As various comments have pointed out, there is an objective reason why the list API from the Prelude favours certain access patterns, and so the question can be usefully answered.

Comment: @duplode: There are good justifications, but I don’t think that means the question is answerable.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker: If you find yourself implementing these specific helper functions all the time, you’re probably overlooking a better solution to the broader problem. And if you mean helper functions in general, well yes, the prelude can’t include every possible helper function. That’s what installing and creating packages is for.

Comment: @Ry- `If you find yourself implementing these specific helper functions all the time, you’re probably overlooking a better solution to the broader problem` - you are `probably` right, it `may` be considered as a code smell.

Comment: @Ry- `the prelude can’t include every possible helper function` - I understand that, but insert, modify, remove seem like very common cases.

Comment: @Ry- `That’s what installing and creating packages is for` - Agreed, and I did try googling for such a package and could not find one.

Comment: @Ry- `I don’t think that means the question is answerable` - I think it does. Because insert, modify, remove seem like very common cases that should be in the Prelude and they are not. There must be a reason why Haskell people decided not to include it in the Prelude. What was that reason?

Comment: @Ry- `There are good justifications, but I don’t think that means the question is answerable.` - I edited my original question to rephrase it in the hopes it would convey a more objective `state of mind` instead of asking for opinions.

Comment: `greed, and I did try googling for such a package and could not find one.` I think I might have found it: `Data.List`.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker: you can use `hoogle` to search for function names and signatures, for example: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D also vote for reopen (did not dv/close vote, btw.).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `you can use hoogle to search for function` - I tried, no success. But Data.List has some of the functions I need.

Comment: The rephrasing isn’t any better (nobody can answer except by quoting the “Haskell people” in question or the people themselves, same as before) and it’s probably a misconception that these are “common” use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prelude is meant to be comprised of a relatively lean set of basic definitions. Below is [a relevant passage](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1110005.6) from the Haskell 2010 Report:

> There are also many predefined library modules, which provide less frequently used functions and types. [...] Separating libraries from the Prelude has the advantage of reducing the size and complexity of the Prelude, allowing it to be more easily assimilated, and increasing the space of useful names available to the programmer.

That being so, use cases beyond the bare essentials, including pretty common ones, will typically be covered by modules other than the Prelude, or libraries other than *base*. (For a related Q&A, see also [*Why Haskell doesn't have split function?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57109229/2751851).)

In your concrete example, modifying, inserting or removing list elements by index have not been deemed common enough to merit inclusion in the Prelude, or even in `Data.List`. A key reason for that is Haskell lists being [geared for sequential, streaming access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9611904/2751851), rather than random access. In situations which require lots of random access, it is expected that users will switch to data structures better suited to the task at hand, such as [sequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Sequence.html), [maps](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) or [vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0). They readily offer analogues for some or all of your functions with adequate performance characteristics. For instance, `Data.Sequence` includes [`update`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:update), [`insertAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:insertAt) and [`deleteAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:deleteAt).

Comment: Thank you very much @duplode! It was very interesting and insightful to read your answer. I am marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Haskell is immutable. It does not make sense to provide „standard“ functions which semantical connotation (from names) might imply mutability and this way of thinking.  It is misleading and wrong, and not only because no actual modification of passed entities happens and always newly created are returned from the functions.

On the other side infinite number of such „more specific“ functions is elementary created based on more generic ones from the language as needed.

Comment: Well, you could also make the point the `sort` has a connotation of in-place ordering – but that's not a problem, precisely because of the convention that everything is immutable (or at least any mutability is explicit in the types). It's unlike in Python, where it could plausibly have either behaviour (and I've more than once tried to use `sort` as a pure function and wondered why it didn't work). FWIW, e.g. [`Set` does have a (pure) `insert` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Set.html#v:insert). The reason it makes sense there it's that it's _efficient_.

Comment: Indeed -- as leftaroundabout notes, it is a practical concern, not a conceptual purity one.

Comment: Haskell has no such rule against imperative function names.

Comment: This was not meant as a rule, rather a more abstract or conceptual view on this.